# How to add a column in a select statement and use ir in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute a select statement in my database but it keeps showing me this message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Edad' to data
>   type int.

The statement is the following:

```
select nroSocio, categoriaId, convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, (FechaNacimiento), getdate())/365.25) as 'Age' 
from Socios 
Where ('Age'< 16 and categoriaId='711141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202')
   or ('Age' > 14 and categoriaId='6F1141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202')
```

I've tried using `CONVERT(INT,'Age')` but the error message is the same. Also, I tried with `'Age' > '14'`, this way the query is executed but it doesn't work okay, it's seems that `'Age' > '14'` is always true.

I'm using `sql server 2012` by the way.

Comment: Why don't use this to calculate AGE?
`DATEDIFF(yy, FechaNacimiento, getdate())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'Age'< 16` is comparing the *string literal* `"Age"` to a number, which is nonsensical.

In addition, you can't reference computed columns in a `where` clause, because the `where` clause is evaluated *before* the computed column.

You could do a subquery:

```
select * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        nroSocio, 
        categoriaId, 
        convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, (FechaNacimiento), getdate())/365.25) as [Age]
    from Socios 
) x
Where (Age < 16 and categoriaId='711141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202')
   or (Age > 14 and categoriaId='6F1141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202')
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Anyway, I tried using the subquery but it said that the sintax was wrong. But I solve the problem using the next query:

select nroSocio, categoriaId, convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, (FechaNacimiento), getdate())/365.25) as 'Edad' 

from Socios Where (convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, (FechaNacimiento), getdate())/365.25)< 16 and categoriaId='711141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202') or (convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, (FechaNacimiento), getdate())/365.25) > 14 and categoriaId='6F1141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202')

Answer (score 0):

use this derived table in your query

```
Select * from (
       select 
            nroSocio, 
            categoriaId, 
            DATEDIFF(yy, FechaNacimiento, getdate()) as Age
       from Socios ) t
Where (Age< 16 and categoriaId='711141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202')
   or (Age > 14 and categoriaId='6F1141DB-2D9C-E411-941D-00155DDA4202')
```